# Procesar más de un resultado en select2

Tags: javascript, select2

estoy obteniendo resultados de select2 a través de ajax, recibe un array

```
        $response[] = array(
            'id' => $site->place->id,
            'text' => $site->domain,
            'site_id' => $site->id,
        );
```

en el javascript en select2 los procesa todos

```
            processResults: function (response) {
                return {
                    results: response,
                };
            },
```

quisiera saber si es posible obtener el "site_id" ya que cuando obtengo el valor con $('#sites_with_place_id').val(); me aparece directamente el campo "id" y no veo cómo poder obtener el "site_id" de la selección

Answer (score 0):

Según la doc (está un poco escondido), la puedes encontrar con un listener al seleccionar una opción:

```
$('#mySelect2').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var data = e.params.data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

La variable data en este caso te debe devolver un objeto con el id, text, y site_id de la opción que hayas seleccionado